# Group nested selected query returning all rows

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to display the data so that only one line is displayed per customer, i'm having trouble with trying to achieve that with my code as its returning all records, can anyone help

```
SELECT customerOrdrs.NAME AS 'Name', 
       customerOrdrs.currentbalance - 
       Sum(COALESCE(customerOrdrs.revisedbalance, 0)) AS 'RevisedBalance', 
       sold AS 'NumberOfItemsSold' 
FROM   customers, 
       (SELECT c.NAME                   AS NAME, 
               c.balance                AS CurrentBalance, 
               i.qty                    AS RevisedBalance, 
               ( Min(s.price) * i.qty ) AS Sold 
        FROM   customers c 
               INNER JOIN sales o 
                       ON c.NAME = o.custname 
               INNER JOIN purchases i 
                       ON i.orderno = o.orderno 
               INNER JOIN contracters s 
                       ON i.item = s.item 
        GROUP  BY c.NAME, 
                  c.balance, 
                  i.qty) customerOrdrs 
GROUP  BY customerOrdrs.NAME, 
          customerOrdrs.currentbalance, 
          sold
```

Comment: You have created a cross join between customers and that subquery. You would do yourself a huge by favor by spending a little formatting this. As it is posted it is very difficult to read. I don't know why you are using this subquery here but you should read this article about using this older style of join. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your data looks but I have reformatted the query and there are a few things I've noticed off the bat.

I have removed the subquery as I don't believe it is necessary - in addition your original query is referring to customer table twice without defining a join

```
Select  [C].[Name] As [Name]
      , [CurrentBalance] = [C].[Balance]
      , [RevisedBalance] = [C].[Balance] - Sum([P].[Qty])
      , [Sold] = ( Min([CO].[Price]) * sum([P].[Qty]) )
From    [CUSTOMERS] [C]
        Inner Join [Sales] [s]
            On [C].[Name] = [s].[custName]
        Inner Join [Purchases] [P]
            On [P].[OrderNo] = [s].[OrderNo]
        Inner Join [Contracters] [CO]
            On [P].[Item] = [CO].[Item]
Group By [C].[Name]
      , [C].[Balance];
```

Comment: Hi Chris, results are not correct, its displaying multiple results per customer

Comment: Tim   43.00   -981.00 61.4400
Tim   43.00   31.00  3.0000
Graham -200.00  -2248.00 122.8800
Graham -200.00  -212.00  30.5400

Comment: @PeterTaylor does that mean that your customers have multiple balances or multiple prices or Qtys?

Comment: The customer has multiple orders and I need to 'sum up' the value off all orders and then count the number of orders the customer has made

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've added a sum on the Qty within the sold field - how's that?

Comment: Hi Chris, still the same Tim 43.00 42.00 0.6900
Tim 43.00 33.00 34.9000

Graham -200.00 -206.00 20.9400
Graham -200.00 -212.00 61.0800

Comment: Its almost there, the reason for the nested query was I had to loop over all supplier items and get the lowest price and then multiple that by the quantity